# Button border appearing within object height

Tags: css

This isn't a major issue as it can easily be tweaked with a bit of css - just something I'm interested to know. Why does the border appear within the height of a button element instead of outside, as per box model? In the example below I have a button element and an anchor element. Both height 30px, with a 1px border. However the button element appears 2px shoter than anchor (which displays correctly at total height 32px).

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Rv7/1/

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using, does it render this way with all browsers?

Comment: Buttons are hard to style using css, just set the `padding` to 0 and look at the difference between firefox and chrome for example.

Comment: Yeah sorry this is in chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding this to the style should resolve your problem

```
box-sizing: content-box
```

This will cause the element to render as you want. I believe that by default buttons render with the border-box behaviour wich causes padding and borders to be added **inside** the box.